# why findLoadedClass method call returns different result？

Tags: java, classloader

consider a custom classloader`class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader｛｝`

if I call `loadClass` as follows

```
ClassLoader loader = new ClassLoader(){}; 
loader.loadClass("java.util.ArrayList");
Method method = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("findLoadedClass", String.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println(method.invoke(loader,"java.util.ArrayList"));
```

it outputs `null`.

But if I replace

```
loader.loadClass("java.util.ArrayList");
```

with

```
Class.forName("java.util.ArrayList",true,loader);
```

it outputs `class java.util.ArrayList`.

Can anyone explain this problem?

Comment: What is `CustomClassLoader`? Since we don't know what that class is and what it does, it's impossible to tell what its `findLoadedClass` method does.

Comment: I believe `findLoadedClass` only checks if _that_ `ClassLoader` has loaded the class, it does not delegate to its parent. Since `ArrayList` is a core class it is not loaded by your custom `ClassLoader`.

Comment: @Jesper CustomClassLoader just extends ClassLoader and inherits ClassLoader ‘s methods. findLoadedClass method is provided by ClassLoader.

Comment: So you could just write `ClassLoader loader = new ClassLoader(){};`?

Comment: @matt yes ,you are right

Comment: @Slaw Calling Class.forName doesn't change anything about which class loaded the ArrayList class, but it does change the output of `findLoadedClass`

Comment: @matt I never said `Class.forName` changes which `ClassLoader` loaded the `Class`. My comments are an attempt to explain that, as far as I understand it, `Class.forName` goes through the delegation process while `findLoadedClass` does not. The latter method's output will only be changed by an invocation of `Class.forName` (or `ClassLoader.loadClass`) if the `Class` happens to be loaded by the `ClassLoader` you invoke `findLoadedClass` on (and not an ancestor).

Comment: @Slaw but that isn't the case. If you call Class.forName, the loaded class is still loaded by the boot strap class loader (unless you're running the source code instead of compiling first), but calling findLoadedClass now returns the class.

Comment: @Slaw here is an executable example. https://ideone.com/5cpVGe you can see `first` equals `c` and returns null for the class loader, which means it was loaded by the bootstrap class loader. Why does the output of 'findLoadedClass' change with the provided class loader?

Comment: @matt Well, I find that confusing. This only seems to be the case with [`Class#forName(String,boolean,ClassLoader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.ClassLoader)) and not [`Class#forName(Module,String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.Module,java.lang.String)) nor [`ClassLoader#loadClass(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @matt Only thing I can think of is the documentation of `findLoadedClass` says (**emphasis** mine): "_Returns the class with the given binary name if this loader has been recorded by the Java virtual machine as an **initiating loader** of a class with that binary name. Otherwise null is returned_". What an initiating loader is seems to be defined by [§5.3 of the Java Virtual Machine Specification (JVMS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3). I guess `Class#forName(String,boolean,ClassLoader)` makes the specified `ClassLoader` the "initiating loader".

Answer (score 0):

The default `ClassLoader` implementation performs class loading in the following sequence:

> 1. Invoke findLoadedClass(String) to check if the class has already
>      been loaded.
> 2. Invoke the loadClass method on the parent class loader. If the parent is null the class loader built-in to the virtual machine is
>      used, instead.
> 3. Invoke the findClass(String) method to find the class.

This is a direct extract taken from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String,%20boolean)).

When you make a call to `loadClass`, your implementation will delegate to the parent classloader before attempting to load it itself. This happens to be your system class loader.

In this case, your class is already on the system ClassLoader's classpath, and so it is loaded.

When you later make a call to `findLoadedClass`, the method only checks if the *specified* ClassLoader has loaded the class. It performs no further delegation.

When you make a call to `method.invoke(loader, "java.util.ArrayList")`, you are trying to find the loaded class in your `CustomerClassLoader`. This fails, because it is the parent ClassLoader that performed the loading instead.

You can prove this by instead invoking the method on the system ClassLoader, like so:

```
method.invoke(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(),"java.util.ArrayList")
```

Comment: But when I if I replace
“loader.loadClass("java.util.ArrayList"); ”with

“Class.forName("java.util.ArrayList",true,loader);”  it outputs “class java.util.ArrayList” How do you explain this ？

Comment: @andyyuan I'm not sure what you're asking here. I think I've already explained it. Calls to `loader.loadClass` will be loaded on `loader`'s parent class loader if possible. Calls to `Class.forName` will be loaded **only** on the given class loader. It works because the two different calls result in two different mechanisms of class loading.

Comment: You didn't mention Class.forName in your post at all. Also, what reference do you have that says the class will be loaded *only* on the given class loader? When you call `Class.forName` it goes through [ClassLoader.loadClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass-java.lang.String-) so I dont' think you've demonstrated why it is different.

Comment: @DanielScarfe That's not the way I see it. when I call Class.forName(“java.util.ArrayList”,true,loader), the class “java.util.ArrayList will be loaded on BootstrapClassLoader.

Comment: @andyyuan Class loading in Java uses a delegation model by default. The algorithm of this model is described in the documentation quoted by Daniel above. Since your custom `ClassLoader` did not _itself_ load the class you're looking for, invoking the `findLoadedClass` method results in `null`, as documented. When you use `Class.forName` or `ClassLoader.loadClass`, however, the delegation mechanism takes effect and you get the class you want; this works because the class you want was loaded (or can be, if not already) by an _ancestor_ of your custom `ClassLoader`.

Comment: @Slaw In fact, I'm confused about "loaded class cache". When I call ClassLoader.loadClass,  The
loaded class don't cache maps class names and initiating loaders
to class type, And then, When I call Class.forName,  The
loaded class  cache maps class names and initiating loaders
to class type.

Comment: @andyyuan I'm not sure I understand what you're confused about. Is it something in the implementation?

Comment: @Slaw yes，here is a article about dynamic loading http://cs.uno.edu/~jaime/Courses/4501/dynamicLoading.pdf 。section 4.1

Comment: Your example doesn't work if you compile your source and run it. `java.util.ArrayList` gets loaded by the bootstrap class loader. It does work when you use 'source mode' though.